# ¿Cómo hago para que Heroku entienda que estoy usando Python 3.6 y no 3.5?

Tags: python, heroku

Implementé una aplicación, que puedes encontrar [en GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot), en Heroku pero el registro me advirtió que:

```
you are using python-3.5.2, which is unsupported
```

Ya tengo Python 3.6 ¿Cómo hago para que Heroku entienda que estoy usando Python 3.6?

Aquí están mis versiones :

```
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

Y aquí está mi `Pipfile`

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"

[packages]
requests = { extras = ['socks'] }

[requires]
python_version = "3.6.5"
```

Comment: Que se muestra la terminal cuando ejecuta: `python --version`

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: [Specifying a Python Runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes). Si tienes problemas con el inglés te ayudo a traducirlo.

Comment: @César Muchas gracias. Sin embargo, agregué mi Pipfile y hicé `$ pipenv lock`  pero no eliminó el mensaje de error : /